# How do I check if a file is selected for <input type="file"> in PHP?

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I want to check if the user has selected an image for upload.  What is the php script to do that after the user has clicked submit...

I tried file_exist(), but that expects a string rather than an array and it seems that only works for an absolute path.  Since I don't know which folder the user is going to upload from, this doesn't work.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`$_FILES` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Tizag Tutorial:  http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

If you do a `print_r($_FILES)`, you will see everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the super global variable `$_FILES`.

[More info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).